# Cannot Read Property 'state' of undefined for this.state

Tags: reactjs, state, react-dom

I'm new to react and I was wonder why I keep getting this cannot read property value of "undefined" error. When i consolelog the this.state.username and this.state.todoList I can see that states updating but only after I clicked the submit button it gives me the error.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class TestNote extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
   this.onChangeTodoList = this.onChangeTodoList.bind(this);

   this.state = {
      username: "",
      todoList: "",
   };
}

onChangeUsername(e) {
   this.setState({
     username: e.target.value,
   });
   console.log(this.state.username);
}

onChangeTodoList(e) {
   this.setState({
     todoList: e.target.value,
   });
 }

 onSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   const todoList = {
     username: this.state.username,
     todoList: this.state.todoList,
  };

console.log(todoList);

axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/list/add", todoList)
  .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="container">
       <form>
         <label>Username: </label>
         <input
           type="text"
           required
           value={this.state.username}
           onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
         />
         <label>TodoList: </label>
         <input
           type="text"
           value={this.state.todoList}
           onChange={this.onChangeTodoList}
         />
         <input type="submit" value="Add This List" onClick={this.onSubmit} />
       </form>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to also bind `this` to your `onSubmit` handler, i.e. `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);` or convert `onSubmit` to an arrow function so `this` is bound *automagically*.

Comment: apart from what @DrewReese mentioned, you can also use es6 that you will not have to bind every time. 
`onSubmit = (e) => {...}`

Comment: Okay that seems to be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your `onSubmit` are losing this context. You should try one of these methods, but I recommend you using arrow function.

- You should `.bind(this)` to `onSubmit`

```js
...
<input type="submit" value="Add This List" onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} />
...
```

- Defined `onSubmit` as an arrow function

```js
...
onSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 const todoList = {
   username: this.state.username,
   todoList: this.state.todoList,
 };
}
...
```

Comment: The first solution works, it gives me an error regarding my backend which means the front end is working, but isn't the second solution what I already have? Does using arrow function make a difference?

Comment: Both your snippets have syntax errors and are therefore not runnable.

Comment: @DrewReese where are there syntax errors? I have a hard time putting code on stack overflow, but there seem to be any syntax errors that vs code is bringing to my attention.

Comment: Did you try running your snippets? Just use code blocks versus runnable code snippet blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You did not bind `onSubmit` function/method to `this`, therefore `this` has no context and would return undefined. You can bind `this` to `onSubmit` in the constructor to fix the error.

Another way to avoid having to bind `this` is to use arrow functions for your class methods/functions as they automatically bind `this` to that function, you won't have to worry about doing it yourself.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       username: "",
       todoList: ""
    };

    //  this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    //  this.onChangeTodoList = this.onChangeTodoList.bind(this);

    //  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeUsername = e => {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.username);
  };

  onChangeTodoList = e => {
    this.setState({
      todoList: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todoList = {
      username: this.state.username,
      todoList: this.state.todoList
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define function in your component without using `arrow function` you have to bind to each function the `this` keyword in the constructor for that function to consider each reference of `this` in if definition to refer to the created component.

Here is the definition of the `bind` method

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So if you have component `Home` define like this

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)  {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: "Jeanne Doe"
      }
    }
    
    handleChangeName () {
        this.setState({name: "John Doe"});
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h2>Welcome {this.state.name}</h2>
            <button onClick={this.handleChangeName}>Change name</button>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Here you get the error that tell you `"TypeError: this is undefined"`**

So to fix that you have to use `bind` like this

```js
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        name: "Jeanne Doe"
      }
      this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
    }
    handleChangeName () {
        this.setState({name: "John Doe"});
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h2>Welcome {this.state.name}</h2>
            <button onClick={this.handleChangeName}>Change name</button>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Or to completely avoid the use of `bind` as you can have so many methods define in your component you can use `arrow function` which look like this

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)  {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: "Jeanne Doe"
      }
    }

    const handleChangeName = () => {
        this.setState({name: "John Doe"});
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h2>Welcome {this.state.name}</h2>
            <button onClick={this.handleChangeName}>Change name</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```